# How to retain selected item of ddl in php?

Tags: php

I have three drop down lists and I need to retain selected item in ddl after form is submitted

e.g. When I click 09 in ddl and submit form then it should display 09 in ddl. Pasting my code for your reference.

```
    echo"<option> Select Day</option>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
{
        if($i<10){
    echo "<option>".str_pad($i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."</option>"; 
        }
            else{
                echo "<option>".$i."</option>"; 
            }       
}
?>
```

Comment: You are missing `value` attr in your options. `<option value="1">01</option>`...

Comment: Most browser will use the tag content as default value is the attribute is not set. I know it may not be W3 compliant, but maybe he has a reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your DDL name attribute is, so I'll pretend

```
<select name="ddl"­>
```

Here's what you code should look like:

```
echo"<option> Select Day</option>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
{
        if(isset($_POST['ddl']) && $_POST['ddl'] == $i)
              $select = " checked='checked'";
        else
              $select = "";
        if($i<10){
    echo "<option " . $select . ">".str_pad($i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."</option>"; 
        }
            else{
                echo "<option " . $select . ">".$i."</option>"; 
            }       
}
?>
```

This is a base example, you should take measure to protect your code against injection.

Comment: $select = " checked='checked'"; at this line it is throwing an error

Comment: here is full code:<select id="day" name="day" required>
 <?php
      
        echo"<option> Select Day</option>";
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
 {
           
            if($i<10){
  echo "<option>".str_pad($i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."</option>"; 
            }
                else{
                    echo "<option>".$i."</option>"; 
                }       
 }
 ?>
</select>

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with the parentesis in the IF on the line before, should be fixed now.